# element not interactable sending key

Tags: python, selenium

Im tryin to input a text into the search bar of the website(https://www.taste.com.au/ ), but I get an error saying Message: element not interactable when i try to send key to the element .

I have tried

```
x = driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(menuName)
```

and

```
x = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@name='q']")))
x.send_keys(abc)
```

and even

```
x = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@class='search-box']")))
    x = WebDriverWait(submitSearchArea,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@name='q']")))
```

I then tried to see if the element was visible

```
print(x.is_displayed())
```

and it comes out as false, but in the website it is visible

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below **CSS_SELECTOR** :

```
h1.text-center+div input
```

**Code :**

```
x = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1.text-center+div input")))
x.send_keys('abc')
```

Comment: This seemed to work, could you explain why css selector worked rather than xpath or by name

Comment: It's because there are 2 elements there located by `//*[@name='q']` so we have to specifically point on the desired element

Comment: @kibb : adding to Prophet comment "Even if you convert this css selector to XPATH " it will work. But CSS SELECTORS are far better locator as compare to xpath cause every browser has same engine for css but different engines for xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Try first clicking on that element and only after that sending a text.

```
x = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.container.search-parallax-content input[name='q']")))
x.click()
x.send_keys(abc)
```

As mentioned by cruisepandey there are 2 elements located by `//*[@name='q']` XPath so we need to be more precise selecting the desired element

Comment: That did not work, got an timeout exception when I used `element_to_be_clickable` @Prophet

Comment: @Prophet : there are two elements with that name. so it may not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 elements with exact same name `q` so first, we need to filter them and check which is displayed.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.taste.com.au/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="") # Driver PATH
driver.get(url)

input_field = None

elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.NAME, "q"))
    ) # All input Elements With "q" name
    

for elem in elements:
    # We need to find the real input field which is displayed on the screen
    if elem.is_displayed():
        input_field = elem

input_field.send_keys("Your Keys")
```